# Convert pipe delimited to comma delimited

Tags: csv

I have a .csv file where the first column contains all the data. The data in each row is |(pipe) delimited . How to I convert it to a file such that I get the appropriate output.

```
Data looks like this-
Ross|30|Red
Joey|32|Blue
Chandler|33|Green
```

```
I want it in separate columns- 
Like
Name       Age   Color
Ross       30    Red
Joey       32    Blue
Chandler   33    Green
```

WHat are the steps to achieve this? I am currently working on a MAC system.

Comment: This can be done in many different ways, no matter your system. Would you like to do it using a graphic program, or a commandline-style conversion ? Or using a programming language ? Your method of choice will influence the answer.

Comment: In addition to uncertainty about your method, you specify "comma delimited" but clearly show example of either fixed-width (padded with spaces) or tab-delimited format.  Can you confirm your actual needs ?